# When using input function "scanf" in Xcode 4's debugging console

Tags: debugging, input, xcode4, console-application, scanf

Here is the problem. When I am using the debugging (GCC) in Xcode 4. It seems I can't input a number in debugging console if I use "scanf" in my program. I have to add a "/" after the number then it can act as usual. Just like the solution provided in [How to Enter Standard Input in Xcode Debugger Console](http://repeatgeek.com/tools/how-to-enter-standard-input-in-xcode-debugger-console/). Appending a slash after a desired input number does not make sense.

For example: 
If the program is something similar:

```
...
int num;
scanf("%d", &num);
...
```

Then when it ran to the line, I have to type "123/", or it won't give me any response.

Does anyone meet the same problem? Is there any solution to solve the problem and make it just like running in standard console environment.

Answer (score 10):

You have to press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @Gerabd Grundy, your answer helps me. I voted.

Comment: Thanks power_scriptor